# Using ASP.NET and C# if statement to show message based on a Checkbox in Access

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-access, if-statement

I'm working on a project where I can show information from an Access Database (Or SQL server I'm using both) on an aspx webpage. I'm working with Visual Studio 2017 and C#.

I'm trying to write an it statement that will state "Your Order has Shipped!" based on if the Shipped row has been marked "Yes". Else, says "Your Order is still in process".

My code so far:

```
protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlDataSource1.DataBind();
        string shipped = Convert.ToString(FindControl("Shipped"));
        if (shipped == "Yes") 
        {
            lblShippingMessage.Visible = true;
            lblShippingMessage.Text = "Your Order has shipped!";
        }
        else
        {
            lblShippingMessage.Visible = true;
            lblShippingMessage.Text = "Your Order is still in process.";
        }
    }
```

My databound items are in a FormView.

```
    <asp:FormView ID="FormView1" 
     DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
     RunAt="server" Width="500px" 
     OnPageIndexChanging="FormView1_PageIndexChanging">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <h2><%# Eval("Name") %></h2>
                <h5>Order ID: <%# Eval("ID") %></h5>
                Location: <%# Eval("Location") %><br />
                Billing Code: <%# Eval("Billing Code") %><br />
                <br />
                Order Detail: <%# Eval("Order Details") %><br />
                Shipped: <%# Eval("Shipped")%>
            </itemtemplate>                          
        </asp:FormView>
```

The problem I am having is that every time I load the page, it shows every record as "Your order is still in progress." How do I make the if statement work where it shows the shipped orders as true and the non-shipped items as false?

I've tried setting the row in Access to Yes/No and working with the control as a bool saying if(shipped != 0), but that resulted in the same issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Cassie

Comment: Have you stepped through your Click event method to see what the actual value of  `shipped` is? It may be that you're expecting 'Yes', but it's coming in as 'yes', or maybe even an entirely different value.

Comment: When in doubt, debug your code. Step through line by line, check every value to see if it matches what you expect.

Comment: @Ingenioushax @mason Thank you guys, I went through and looked at the value of  `shipped` and it said null. I tried converting, initializing as a string, object, and it all stated null. Any ideas?

Comment: You don't have a control named shipped in your aspx file. Try adding in something like `<asp:Label name="shipped" id="shipped" runat="server" text=Eval("Shipped")/>` Something along those lines. If you want to get the value from a control using `FindControl(...)` you need to have a control object for it to look for.